# How to change Date and time format in Excel

Tags: excel, simpledateformat

I have Rowvalue as "01-07-2020  10:47:00" in Single Cell in Excel, I want to change the same values as "2020-07-01T10:37". The character "T" should be in between the date and time.

**Current output:**

```
01-07-2020  10:47:00
```

**Expected output:**

```
2020-07-01T10:37
```

someone, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you clarify if you actually want to subtract 10 minutes from the existing time?

If you do you could simply use this:

```
=A1-TIME(0,10,0)
```

As for the formatting, all you need to do is apply this custom formatting.

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm
```